# How to increase text font size system-wide on iOS?

Tags: ios, accessibility

I want to effect an increase in system-wide font size for both built-in and third-party apps on iOS 9.x. What is best approach between Option 1 & 2 below? Do I need to use a combination of settings from 1 & 2?

Option 1: Dynamic Type slider preferred reading size (under Settings | Display & Brightness | Text Size). Assume this is 'the right way' bur seems many apps do not support this API.

Option 2: Accessibility 'Larger Text Sizes' toggle *and* slider (under Settings | General | Accessibility). Am guessing this is a more brute-force approach.

Answer (score 1):

You are gonna need a jailbroken iphone and Bytafont2 installed.

http://ioshacker.com/how-to/change-system-wide-font-iphone-ipad-bytafont-2

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. However It is really depressing if this is the best support that iOS can offer.

Comment: yeah it is quite restricting